# Can LibreOffice Draw run multi-threaded?

Tags: libreoffice

When working with heavy files on LibreOffice Draw, it only uses 1 of my CPU cores at 100% capacity and others are sitting idle.  Difficult with heavy files.

Is there a way to make LibreOffice Draw run multi-threaded?

Many thanks

Comment: 'multithreading' requires the program to be *built* for multithreading.  This is a question that should be sent to Libre Office upstream, not Ask Ubuntu, because if the program doesn't support multithreading in the sense you mean "use multiple CPU cores" then that's not something we can 'make' work - the program has to be built/designed to be multithreaded

Answer (score 0):

Using LibreOffice 6 Calc, navigate to Tools → Options → LibreOffice Calc Click on Calculate Under CPU threading settings, check the box next to Enable multi-threaded.